# display bug on nexus 4

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm coding an app for android devices and I have a problem when it run on a nexus 4 phone. It work well on Galaxy S3/Note 2 and on some other devices.

I create an AVD with nexus 4 parameter but it works on it.

The problem is about the display of my main activity. It's like a mosaic picture.

There isn't anything in logcat and I don't know how to correct it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Titre_fav"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc_star_logo"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fav" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/fav_scroll">
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/console"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_to_foud"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/nav_to_found_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_to_settings"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nav_to_settings_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I correct it ?

I can't post my screenshot because I don't have 10 reputation.

---

Edit : I can know post screnshot, thanks :)

What it may look like :
[image: correct screen]

What it's look :
[image]

Comment: here's a +1.. post a picture... :) .. and Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Post a picture. +1 from me!

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, I don't know if it will work for you. But try to add a background to your xml file. Like: `android:background="#000000"` in the top level Layout.